# Using XSLTCompiledTransform on XSL with special characters?

Tags: c#, .net, xslt

I'm trying to transform a XML using:

```
    private string transformXML(string xml_data, string xml_style)
    {
        //generemos un html temporal para mostrar la transformacion
        string outfile = Path.GetTempFileName().Replace(".tmp", ".html");

        XslCompiledTransform proc = new XslCompiledTransform();

        using (System.IO.StringReader sr = new System.IO.StringReader(xml_style))
        {
            using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr))
            {
                proc.Load(xr);
            }
        }

        string resultXML;

        using (System.IO.StringReader sr = new System.IO.StringReader(xml_data))
        {
            using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr))
            {
                using (System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter())
                {
                    proc.Transform(xr, null, sw);
                    resultXML = sw.ToString();
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(outfile, resultXML);

                    return outfile;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Using this, I get an `System.Xml.Xsl.XslLoadException` on the line `porc.Load(xr)`, due to  an illegal `'<'`.  The illegal character in the `<` in this line:

```
<xsl:when test="$value &lt; 19">
```

which is, as you see, escaped. Possibly, Xml.Create() is unescaping my <, what's the way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respectfully: I Suggest this might have something to do with the encode/decode questions in the caller of your method -> in the way in which the XSL is being loaded from your source/before it is passed in to your "transformXML" method.

To review my thoughts on this I did the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

namespace XSLPlayPlace
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string stylesheetText = File.ReadAllText("stylesheet.xsl");

            var program =
                new Program().transformXML("<data><item>1</item><item>2</item><item>19</item><item>1</item></data>", stylesheetText);
        }

        private string transformXML(string xml_data, string xml_style)
        {
            [... snip ... your code copied exactly as per the question ...]
        }
    }
}
```

And added a file to the console app, setting it to 'copy always' where the file contents are as follows (random XSL scribblings just to get the syntax OK around the XSL node you have a question about):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template name="test" match="//data/item">
    <xsl:variable name="value" select=". + 1"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$value &lt; 19">
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am quite happy that this does not match correctly and doesn't hit any nodes or return any values ... but what it does demonstrate is that the XSL compiles fine.

If you debug your code be very careful how the debugger visualises the XSL you have passed in -> use the text visualiser from the 'context menu' in the QuickWatch perhaps? Might illuminate the problem.

Comment: It's loaded from a temp file, which has the correct '&lt;' character. I load it onto a string using System.IO.File.ReadAllText(outfile), you think that might be it?

Comment: I don't think so: since System.IO.File.ReadAllText() is what I use in the above example and that works fine. I would be looking at building up the XSL file piece by piece until it breaks on calling proc.Load(xr).

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that after adding the comment. Well, I'll try your suggestion.